# synonym for spacious

Tags: meaning, synonyms

[image]

[image]

Can you guys tell what the right answer is? imo the right answer is (B)

Comment: @JJJ and co: There's a lot of nuance in this this question which would stretch many native speakers to elucidate, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the four words only *Luxurious* does not necessarily imply dimensions in any way.  There are luxurious dog kennels.

Of the remainder

- *Wide* means lots of width  but makes no statement about length or height/depth.
- *Big* means the same as large but it is an ugly word that is not suited to a sales pitch, as here.
- *Large* means the same as big, but it's posher somehow, and therefore the closest to *Spacious*